# Import-loop in R (read.csv)

Tags: r, loops, csv, text, import

I tried to import *.csv files with ongoing numbers in the mid of the name - so I tried to use a for-loop to generate the number and paste it into the filenames:

```
for (Number in 20:30){
  (paste("Test.",Number,"File"))<- read.csv("~/Test.-",Number,"File".csv", sep=";", comment.char="#")

}
```

How can I avoid the blank, so the Import does work? Any other Suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to use paste inside the read.csv function too, to create a string which represents your file name. So read.csv(paste("~/Test.-",Number,"File.csv", sep="", comment.char="#"). There are better ways to use list.files() and using apply function if all files are in the same folder. Why did you use sep=";" ??

Comment: The sep=";" is between the rows in the *.csv-File. They are all in one Folder! What would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: can you just print the first two lines of any 1 of your .csv or a sample that represents the format. csv files should not have a ";" in it.

Comment: As mentioned: the format is row1;row2;row3;... and it's set by the source. Where is the Problem handling these Data?

Comment: I think you need to clean the files even before reading them in R and substitute the ";" with "" OR you can directly read the file like this: paste("Test.",Number,"File",sep=""))<-read.csv(paste("~/Test.-",Number,"File.csv", sep="", comment.char="#") but in this case the last column will have a semi colon at the end. You need to make sure the source does not give a semi colon in the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwer by @manaR solves the problem of the white space. The `stringr`package str_c allows you to do that also. You can use `assign` to create a new variable with the right name in the user environment.

```
require(stringr)
for (Number in 20:30){
        file<- read.csv(str_c("~/Test.-",Number,"File",".csv"), sep=";",comment.char="#")
        # assign value to the variable name x 
        assign(x=str_c("Test.",Number,"File"),value=file,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
      }



   # this example with the winprogressbar only works under windows
    # it allows you to load all the files with extension .csv in one directory


    datawd<-"c:/path/to/mydirectory/"
    listoffiles<-list.files(datawd) # list of files
    # find out which files have extensions csv
    listoffiles<-listoffiles[grep(".csv",listoffiles)]
    # creating the full path
    mypaths<-str_c(datawd,listoffiles)
    progress<-utils::winProgressBar(title = "loading csv files",
            label = "progression %",
            min = 0,
            max = length(mypaths), 
            initial = 0,
            width = 400)
    for (i in 1:length(mypaths)){
        utils::setWinProgressBar(progress,i,label=listoffiles[i])       
        file<- read.csv(mypaths, sep=";",comment.char="#")
        # assign value to the variable name x 
        assign(x=str_c("Test.",Number,"File"),value=file,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfect, but I am also interested in the mentioned "better ways" in one folder? Any links here in Community?

Comment: @HerrStudent Check out the list.files() and lapply() in R That will give you a single list object containing data of all files as data.frames in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra argument to `paste()`

```
for (Number in 20:30){
  name <- paste("Test.",Number,"File.csv", sep = "")
  name <- read.csv(name, sep=";", comment.char="#")

}
```

`sep=""` will remove the space in the name.

Comment: If your file is a csv file it should be separated by a comma, not ; .So that might be another issue.

Comment: The format of the files is fixed from the source. What's the difference in seperation by "," or ";" oder "TAB". I just have to set the Value in read.csv - Thanks!

Comment: If they are really separated by ; , that is fine, but as @Tushar says, csv should not have ; separator, but a comma. After all they are called comma separated values = csv

Comment: Okay - that's kind of Industry definition: I know it's called "comma seperated values" - but in reality it's semikolon.

Comment: @HerrStudent comma separate values means the columns are separated by "," while the rows are separated by "\n\r" generally or return key.

Comment: @Tushar - the export of the Source does not allow to separate as usual! I have to deal with the data I get ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (number in 20:30){
    name<-paste("Test.-",number,"File",sep="")
    name<-read.csv(paste(filename,".csv",sep=""))
   }
```

by default if you don't specify sep="" in paste(), the sep is set to " ". 
But still in the last column you will get a ";" which you will have to replace using the gsub function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `","` in `sep=","` helped me. Thanks to manaR, Cedric .

```
for (i in 1:96){
  d <- read.csv(str_c("GRID_",Number,".csv"), sep=",",comment.char="#")
  source("Function_for grid.R")
}
```